# How to add background color to a set of columns of a pandas dataframe and save that coloured dataframe into a csv/excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Below Dataframe I'm using

```py
data = {

    'ID1': [1, 1, 2, 4],
    'ID2': [1, 2, 1, 1],
    
    'A': [1, 2, 3, np.nan],
    
    'B': [4, 5, 6, ''],
    
    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    
    'D': [4, 5, 6, 7],
    
    'E': [1, 2, 3, np.nan],
    
    'F': [4, 5, 6, 7]
}
```

I have set of columns in a dataframe and and below condition I want achieve

1. if in a particular set of columns all columns of that particular row is equal then all column in that particular set should be highlighted with lightgreen color
2. If not equal then lightcoral color
3. If any cell of that set of col is null or blank then yellow
   Here ID1 and ID2 together I'm using as a primary key
   Using below set

```
\[A,B],\[C,D,E,F\]
```

I tried the below code;

```
column_set = [['A','B'],['C','D','E','F']]

def highlight _columns(x):
    unique_values=x.unique()

    if len(unique_values) ==1:
        return ['background-color: lightgreen']*len(x)

    elif pd.isnull(x).any() or x.eq('').any(): 
        return ['background-color: yellow']*len(x)

    else: 
        return ['background-color: lightcoral']*len(x)

    for col_set in column_set:
        df[col_set] = df[col_set].apply(highlight_columns,axis=1)
```

Can anyone please help me out

Comment: So it means no column(s) match first condition in sample data?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, correct

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
data = {

    'ID1': [1, 1, 2, 4],
    'ID2': [1, 2, 1, 1],
    
    'A': [1, 2, 3, np.nan],
    
    'B': [1, 5, 6, ''],
    
    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    
    'D': [4, 5, 6, 7],
    
    'E': [1, 2, 3, np.nan],
    
    'F': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
column_set = [['A','B'],['C','D','E','F']]

def highlight_columns(x):
    #set no color
    out = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    for col_set in column_set:
        #select DataFrame columns by list
        df1 = x[col_set]
        #compare if same values per rows
        m1 = df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)
        #compare if any missing values of empty strings
        m2 = df1.fillna('').eq('').any(axis=1)

        #set default color
        out[col_set] = 'background-color: lightcoral' 

        #set colors by masks
        out.loc[m1, col_set] = 'background-color: lightgreen'
        out.loc[m2, col_set] = 'background-color: yellow'
        
    return out

df.style.apply(highlight_columns, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

[image: pic]

Another similar solution:

Comment: Thank you it's working but I don't want color on primary key('ID1' ,'ID2') how can I skip that column here??

Comment: Thank you jezrael, it's working as expected.